# Conditional expectation for exogeneity

Tags: regression, econometrics, conditional-expectation

I am reading about ordinary least squares regression, and I came across this assumption called "strict exogeneity", defined such that $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon | X] = 0$ for error $\epsilon$ and regressor $X$. My question is what does it mean for this to equal 0? Isn't the conditional expectation of two random variables $\mathbb{E}[A|B]$ a random variable itself? This would imply $\epsilon  = 0$ always which doesn't make sense so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points:

1. $E[\epsilon|X] = 0$ doesn't contradict the fact that $E[\epsilon|X]$ is a random variable -- "$0$" is a legit random variable, more precisely, a *degenerate* random variable.
2. $E[\epsilon|X] = 0$ does not imply $\epsilon = 0$. Consider the very simple counterexample: $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$ and $X$ is any random variable that is independent of $\epsilon$. It then follows that $E[\epsilon|X] = E[\epsilon] = 0$. Obviously, $\epsilon$ is not zero.

From statistical perspective (I am not an econometrician), $E[\epsilon|X] = 0$ just means that the noise at any $X = x$ does not have any tendency.  In particular, it implies that $\epsilon$ and $X$ are uncorrelated, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600554/if-text-e-varepsilonx-0-why-is-textcov-varepsilon-x-0/600555#600555).

Answer (score 5):

You need to carefully gauge the implications of strict exogeneity: The assumption $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i\mid \mathbf X]=0, ~\forall i\in\{1, 2,\ldots, n\}$ which for random samples ($\{y_i, \mathbf x_i\}$ being i.i.d. across all observations) mean $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i\mid \mathbf x_i]=0$ does imply $\mathbf E[\varepsilon_i]=0$ (but not vice-versa) as has been correctly emphasized in Zhanxiong's [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/620969/362671) (+1) which also addresses your main concern that $\varepsilon_i$ need not be zero. What the assumption actually dictates is the regressors have to be orthogonal to the error terms across all observations, for $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i\mid x_{jk}]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i\mid \mathbf X]\mid x_{jk}]=0,$ and **not** $\varepsilon_i=0.$

As a side-pointer, conditional expectation is **not** *a* random variable. It's an equivalence class. Also, if $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}$ in $(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, \mathbb P) $ and $X=c$ a.e., then $c\in \mathbb E[X\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}].$ In fact, it is $\{c\}\subset \mathbb E[c\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}]$ and definitely **not** $\{c\}= \mathbb E[c\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}]$ (for reference, check $\rm [II]$). I digress though.

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ Econometrics, *Fumio Hayashi,* Princeton University Press, $2000, $ pp. $8-9, ~12-13.$

$\rm [II]$ Martingales and Stochastic Analysis, *J.Yeh,* World Scientific, $1995, $ Theorem $\rm B. 5.$